# ASP.NET/MVC UIX Frameworks?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

are there any .net UI frameworks similar to what https://vaadin.com/home has to offer for java?

One thing that I have noticed is the lack of shared front end tools/components/layouts/controls other the hodge podge of jquery stuff out there.

It would be nice to have a UI tool box that is consistent for rich looking UI's without being a true UI Designer.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MVC Microsoft is (at least presently) pushing jQuery as their client-side toolkit of choice, so jQueryUI would be the official "visual components" suite if anything would be.

Many of the .NET component vendors, like Telerik or DevExpress, also include MVC extensions that replicate their traditional ASP.NET controls but they're commercial products. (We own DevExpress at $DAYJOB but thus far none of our MVC applications have found cause to use them.)

With MVC being relatively new, compared to ASP.NET or Windows Forms, I wouldn't be surprised if a few UI frameworks gradually appeared and got "unofficial community approval" as the way to go for MVC UI but right now, I don't believe such an animal exists.